# How to force new assignation in loop in Lua?

Tags: lua

I would like to know how to force a new assignation in a loop:

```
for file in lfs.dir( lfs.currentdir() .. "/content" ) do
    if lfs.attributes( lfs.currentdir() .. "/content/" .. file, "mode" ) == "file" then
        if file:sub( 0, 1 ) ~= "." then

            local article = Article:new( lfs.currentdir() .. "/content/" .. file )
            table.insert( self.articles[article.lang], article )

        end
    end
end
```

When I run this piece of code through a debugger I can see that the article variable has always the same address in memory, so every element of the `self.articles` table is exactly the same.

How can I force the assignation of a new memory space without deleting the older one (who should be referenced in the table)?

**Edit**

I currently use 30log: https://github.com/Yonaba/30log

Article inherits a Content class:

*content.lua (part)*

```
local content = class()
content.__name = "Content"

function content:__init( file_path )

    self.title    = _( "Untitled document" )
    -- ... other declarations like this, nothing less, nothing more

end

-- Some methods follow
```

*article.lua (full)*

```
local article = Content:extends()

article.__name = "Article"

function article:__init( file_path )

    article.super:__init( file_path )

end

return article
```

**Edit 2**

The call can be viewed "in context" here : https://github.com/martin-damien/frankenstein/blob/master/pieces/site.lua#L151

Thanks,

Damien

Comment: If you declare article outside the loops and continue to assign it in the loops does it work?

Comment: Please post the code of the `Article:new` function.  I suspect that is where the bug is (specifically, it should set `self` to a new table and I am guessing it does not.)

Comment: @Bill It doesn't change anything.

Comment: @finnw I hadded who you wanted to know to the question under **Edit**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with the code in your GitHub repository, but one that is probably related to that question is [this](https://github.com/martin-damien/frankenstein/blob/c4aafadd8f14c4e745a181b1fa9bafd5e99a1063/pieces/content.lua#L14). Lua table indexing starts from 1 so you assign `nil` as the default language for articles...

If I fix that and other things like the fact that you cannot [call a method in the constructor](https://github.com/martin-damien/frankenstein/blob/c4aafadd8f14c4e745a181b1fa9bafd5e99a1063/pieces/content.lua#L34) with 30log, your code "works" (i.e. after this loop there are several articles in the relevant table).

Comment: https://github.com/martin-damien/frankenstein/blob/c4aafadd8f14c4e745a181b1fa9bafd5e99a1063/pieces/content.lua#L14 take the first element of a table loaded from a `settings.lua` file. So there is neither `nil` as value. But removing the call from the constructor and moving it after the constructor works very well (combined with the older post of @finnw)

Comment: What I meant is that if that table looks like https://github.com/martin-damien/frankenstein/blob/c4aafadd8f14c4e745a181b1fa9bafd5e99a1063/frankenstein.lua#L43 it doesn't work. `languages[0]` is `nil`, `languages[1]` is `"en"`...

Comment: What kind of problems did you saw on my code ? (I started to lear Lua some months ago as a hobby and I know that I have a lot things to learn).

Comment: Thanks for noticing `languages[0]` it's something I still forgot with Lua.

Comment: @MARTINDamien Mostly you use too many globals :) You should make more things local, it would be more readable. Also, stuff like: https://github.com/martin-damien/frankenstein/blob/c4aafadd8f14c4e745a181b1fa9bafd5e99a1063/frankenstein.lua#L70 you set `f.site.languages` only if `languages` is set, but it has no default so if `languages` is not set it breaks.

Comment: @MARTINDamien Btw if you have questions about Lua in general that don't fit on Stack Overflow join http://luafr.org/ (I saw you're French :p). There's almost no trafic currently but at least I am on it to answer.

Comment: Thank you very much I will try to enhance my code and if I have questions I will ask on the list.